# SF Short Story - Fritz Leiber?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, fritz-leiber

I can't remember where or when I read this short story, but for some reason Leiber's name comes to mind. Aliens (for a reason I can't remember) decide to test the human race using one man, an average American Joe. This test begins by giving him (without his knowledge) a razor blade that never wears out. After a while Joe notices this; it disturbs him so much he finally throws it away without ever wondering where it came from: He fails the test. I can't remember the other tests, but Joe fails them all. The disgusted aliens decide to get rid of Joe; one of the gifts was a kind of ESP and Joe, who I think was sitting in a public place like a park, perceives a bullet-like object drifting in space. He mentally follows the bullet as it plunges down through the atmosphere and blasts right through his head! I remember thinking how unfair it was. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Might be "Bullet with His Name". It is a Fritz Leiber story, as you suggested. Check out the story at this [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/51436/51436-h/51436-h.htm) link with the story transcribed from *Galaxy Science Fiction*, July 1958 ([isfdb.org](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46027)).

> The third morning, face lathered, he flipped open the razor and lifted
> it out.
>
> "You're through," he said to it silently. "I've had the experience
> before of getting bum shaves by trying to save a penny by pretending
> to myself that a wornout blade was still sharp enough, when it
> obviously couldn't be. Or maybe—" he grinned a little wryly—"maybe I'd
> almost get one more shave out of you and then you'd fall to pieces
> like the Wonderful One Horse Shay and leave me with a chin full of
> steel porcupine quills. No, thanks."
>
> So Ernie Meeker pushed through the little slot beside the mirror and
> heard tinkle faintly down and away the first of the Little Gifts, the
> Everlasting Razor Blade. One hundred and fifty thousand years later,
> it turned up, bright and shining, in the midst of a small knob of red
> iron oxide excavated by an archeological expedition of multi-brachs
> from Antares Gamma. Those wise history-mad beings handed it about
> wonderingly, from tentacle to impatient tentacle.

He is killed with a silver bullet, which he can sense coming:

> Up there in space with him, right at his elbow, so close that he could
> reach out and touch it, was a tiny silver cylinder about as big as a
> hazelnut, domed at one end, reflecting sunlight from one point in a
> way that would have been blinding enough except that Ernie's ghost
> eyes were immune to brightness.
>
> As he reached out to examine it, the thing darted away from him as if
> at some imperious summons, like a bit of iron jumping through a
> magnetic field.
>
> But in spite of its enormous acceleration, Ernie's ghost was able to
> follow it in its downward plunge. It kept just ahead of his
> outstretched fingertips.
>
> The brown granules that were Earth's surface grew in size. The tiny
> metal cylinder began to glow with more than reflected sunlight. It
> turned red, orange, yellow and then blazing white as atmospheric
> friction transformed it into a meteor.
>
> Ernie's ghost, immune to friction and incandescence alike, followed it
> as it dove toward its target—for even though Ernie had never heard of
> a Juxtaposer and how it brought objects together, he had the feeling,
> from the dizzy speed of the meteor's plunge, that it yearned for
> something.
>
> He knew most meteors vaporized or exploded, but this did not, even
> when Earth's brown surface grew rivers and roads. Suddenly there was a
> cloudbank ahead; then, in the white, there appeared an almost circular
> hole toward the very center of which the meteorite plunged.
>
> Everything was happening very fast now, but his ghost senses were able
> to keep pace. As they plunged through the cloud-ring and the green
> landscape below grew explosively, he saw the white tower, the trees,
> the curving drives, and the clearing which was now the target.
>
> There was still time to escape. Lying on the warm grass, with death
> lancing down from the sky at miles a second, he had merely to roll
> over.
>
> But it was simply ... too ... much ... work....

The story ends with the police investigating the death. They discover that the bullet **literally** had his name on it:

> A moment later, he put down the magnifier, snatched up the pocketbook
> found on the dead man and rechecked some cards in it. The bullet
> dropped from the forceps, rolled a few inches. The lieutenant sat back
> in his chair, breathing a little hard.
>
> "This is one for the books, all right!" he told himself. "I've heard a
> lot of people, soldiers especially, talk about such bullets, but I
> never expected to see one!"
>
> For under the magnifying glass, finely engraved in very tiny letters,
> he had read the words: ERNEST WENCESLAUS MEEKER.

Comment: It is the story - thanks! I tracked it down and I read it in a 1962 anthology by Groff Conklin. Thanks again.